# Menu mouse over animation: having an highlight reflect displayed above the menu link

Tags: html, css, mouseover

I have a problem that seem unsolvable, due to HTML limitations.

Here is a capture that may explain you the whole thing: 
[image: imgage]

#### #

As you can see, I want a transparent part to move above the mouseovered menu item.

But as I am thinking that, I find out that this won't work cause the menu item will loose the :hover stat as soon as the transparent part will arrive below the mouse.

If where were with actionscript3, this would be easily done by setting the .mouseEnabled property on my transparent part, so that it isn't considered by the mouse.

Do you know if something similar is possible with html? Do you have other solutions/track to follow, to success what I wanted to do?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is it acceptable to use javascript and/or jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to accomplish this kind of effects is to use the CSS property **z-index**. For instance if your menu structure looks like this:

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Master/PHD Education</a>
      <span>Introduction, Master &amp; Doctorans</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="transparent_overlap"></div>
</div>
```

The trick is to work with 3 layers, the first is the background of the menu (brown and white) which could be assigned to the div, then the second layer is the transparent overlap, and the one in the front is the LI which has the link. With css it would look like:

```
#menu{
   background:..
}

#transparent_overlap{
   background:..transparent effect..
}

li{
   position:relative;
   z-index:3;
}
```

Now you only need to move the transparent overlap to the current hovered option with javascript.

Comment: Hi! Yes you'll right! I just didn't thought about that. I'll try to do that: 1: background with images/texts, 2: transparent pad, 3: transparent div/ul with link displayed block, to active the menus. Thank you for your help!